# Two Counterfeit Coins Out of n Coins

Tags: algorithms

I have an amount of $n$ coins and I know that $n-2$ of them are 'regular' and $2$ are fake, as one is lighter than the rest and the other is heavier than the rest, and the sum of both of them is as the sum of two regular coins.

I'm thinking about the conditions:

1. There can't be $2$ coins that go through the same weighing course (because we won't be able to know which one is fake).
2. On each weighing, number of coins on each side has to be the same, #L=#R (because there is no meaning to fake/real coins if I don't weigh them against the same number of coins on the other hand).

Now, I tried some weighing distributions that fit both these conditions, but most of them still don't give me all the $n(n-1)$ possible answers.

I need help finding the last condition for this problem.

Comment: Ummm.....what problem?

Comment: The actual problem is finding minimum number of weighing's but that doesn't matter. I just want the last condition for this to work

Comment: @user76508 if you aren't looking for minimum tries, the naive brute force works well. $n\choose2$

Comment: i am looking for minimum tries

Comment: There's a lot of potential here because you didn't state your problem in the post, and then you made contradictory statements about it in the comments. I'd suggest to edit the post to clearly state the problem. If I understand correctly, the problem is to identify both counterfeit coins in a minimum number of weighings. If so, you still need to specify whether this is meant on average, in the best case or in the worst case.